# Removing index.html from url with ./

Tags: html

I read somewhere that I can add a href="./" on any page in any sub-directory to send the user to the root index.html file, however this doesn't seem to be working. As the title suggests I am trying to not have /index.html in the URL when the user clicks a home link

Comment: So what's wrong with `<a href="http://whatever.com/index.html">Home</a>`?

Comment: in a subfolder, it won't work...

Comment: @Bartdude Am talking about absolute path :)

Comment: "this doesn't seem to be working" — If it doesn't do what you expect, what does it do?

Comment: Just use a `"/"` (no period).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then just use :

```
<a href="/">home</a>
```

or

```
<a href="/index.html">home</a>
```

Comment: Awesome, "/" works. Obviously... I don't want to use /index.html... because the URL will show that.

Comment: yep, I placed it there just in case :-)

Comment: also you can do things like <a href="/?var=1">send...</a> will send the var 1 to the index page on the server...

Answer (score 0):

If you are in www.yoursite.com/dir/ and you want to go to your root folder you must use `../` instead of `./`

If you want to go back from www.yoursite.com/dir/dir2/dir3/ to your root dir you have to write: `../../../` 
The best solution probably would be the full path to your root folder:  `www.yoursite.com/`

Comment: and what if his site has multiple domain names ?